# Update JDBC Database table using storage handler and Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, hive-udf

I have read that using Hive JDBC storage handler
(https://github.com/qubole/Hive-JDBC-Storage-Handler),
the external table in Hive can be created on different databases (MySQL, Oracle, DB2) and users can read from and write to JDBC databases using Hive using this handler.
My question is in the update .
If we use hive.14 where Hive update/delete is supported and use storage handler to point an external table to a JDBC database table, will it allow us to update the database table as well when we fire the update query from Hive end?

Answer (score 0):

> You can not update an external table in hive.

In hive only transcational tables support ACID properties. By default transactions are configured to be off. So to create transaction tables you need to add **'TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true')'**  in your create statement.

There are many limitations to it. One of which is you cannot make external tables to be an ACID table because external tables are beyond the control of hive compactor.

To read more on this click [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions)